# Using python 3 when the default is python 2.7

Tags: python

I installed python3 with homebrew and can access it with python3 command in terminal.

I'm installing a command line app that needs python3. When I try to use it it says:

> Python 3.3+ required

When I do python --version it reports python 2.7.

How can I get the app to use python3?

Comment: you should use `python3 --version`  to check.

Comment: Does Homebrew install python in a framework?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there is no other application to use the python2.7, you can use alias `python` to `python3`:

In the `~/.bashrc`:

add the `alias python=python3`

Comment: Yes I know. I'm asking how to get the app to use python3.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so if you already have python 3.3 or more, then:

1. Open the script in an text editor(TextEdit, vim, etc.)
2. Replace all `python` with `python3`
3. Save and exit

... or just do like @aircraft said, alias it if nothing else uses py2.

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way although I don't get consistent results with these commands on different Macs.  Your milage may vary:

```
1. install homebrew if you dont have it
2. brew install zlib
3. brew install python (to get system level python3; this step is optional)
4. brew install pyenv
5. pyenv install 3.7.0  (to get shimmed python3)
6. pyenv versions
7. pyenv global 3.7.0
8. python --version  (should say 3.7.0)
```

Secondly, I might add this to my bash profile:

```
# put in .bash_profile
export PATH=".:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/sw/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.pyenv/shims" # add Python version manager 'brew install pyenv'
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
echo "Python shimmed: " + $(pyenv which python)
```